# FadeIn class for multiple usage

Tags: jquery, click, hover, toggle

I want a simple Jquery Solution for hovering over the class 'container' and fade in the 'overlay. In this simple Jquery code, all 'overlay's of all 'container's will be displayed. Does anybody knows a simple solution for fadeing just the 'overlay' for the 'overlay' within this class?

Thanks.

```
$('.overlay').hide();
$('.container').hover(function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeToggle(300);
});

<!-- container 01 -->
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>   
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- container 02 -->
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>   
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- container 03 -->
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>   
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.overlay').fadeToggle(300);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/owehim/1/

Comment: hey dude, I already tried this solution. But it doesn't work :( Don't know why! All 'overlay's will be displayed.

Comment: do you have an explanation for that? or any other solution?

Comment: `$('.overlay')` searches *all* elements with this classes. That's why all overlays get toggled in your example. In my example we search all overlays inside `$(this)` which is the hovered `.container`.